# Hazelcast map acts quite intermittently

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am using Hazelcast map to store a table from the DB. It has approximately 10000 records in it.

It works absolutely fine in the first round i.e.

```
hazelcastContext.getMap("EmployeeRecords").get({Emp_ID});
```

It always returns the Employee object successfully

But calling it the second time I have no clue why but it succeeds randomly for about 50,000 to 60,000 times and returns null for rest of the calls.

The Emp_ID is just a String.

The `<time-to-live>0</time-to-live>` is set to 0 so there is no expiry on the data.

The eviction policy is set to 20 but the heap never gets filled as 10000 records is nothing.

Would anyone know why this might be happening.

Both the times I am accessing hazelcast map in a multi-threaded way, would that be something that can cause this. Surprisingly if that is the culprit it doesnt fail the first time.

Comment: Please add your config and sample code to the question. Also, it would be great if you can add some reproducible code for others to test.

Comment: agree with @A.K.Desai, reproducer would help a lot!

Comment: @A.K.Desai VikGamov Guys I am really sorry for posting this so late. But I realized after being frustrated for a few hours that there were four hazelcast configurations in the project and I was looking at the wrong configuration. My code was actually pointing to faulty configuration that had 100 second time out. And my second call was always approximately after that period of time. Hence some who were lucky were accessed before 100 secs rest returned null.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. You can add that as answer and close it.